# Do we have the range projection $r(TP)\downarrow 0$ as $P\downarrow 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a closed (possibly unbounded) operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $P$ be a projection on $\mathcal{H}$. Do we have the range projection $r(TP)\downarrow 0$ as $P\downarrow 0$?

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is bounded. Then T is a linear combination of 4 unitary operators (see Page 209, Reed, Simon, Vol1 of Methods of mathematical physics. Functional analysis). Now, we consider unitary operator $U$. It is easy to see that $r(UP) = UP U^*$, which decreasing to $0$ as $P\downarrow 0$. So, $r(TP)\downarrow 0$ as $P\downarrow 0$.

Now, if $T$ is unbounded. Note that $r(E^{|T|}[n,\infty)|T|) \ge r(E^{|T|}[n,\infty)|T|P)$, we have
\begin{align*} \langle r(|T| P)x,x\rangle &= \langle r(E^{|T|}[0,n)|T| P)x,x\rangle + \langle r(E^{|T|}[n,\infty)|T| P)x,x\rangle\\
&\le \langle r(E^{|T|}[0,n)|T| P)x,x\rangle + \langle r(E^{|T|}[n,\infty)|T|)x,x\rangle.\end{align*}
When $n$ is large enough, the right hand side is decreasing to $0$ ***if $E^{|T|}[n,\infty)\downarrow 0$***(I know a very large amount of operators satisfying this property). Also, for every $n$,  $r(E^{|T|}[0,n)|T| P) \downarrow  0$ as $P\downarrow 0$. So, $r(|T|P)\downarrow 0$ and therefore, $r(TP)\downarrow 0$.